# returning user entered values from a custom dialog box c#

Tags: c#, combobox, return, dialog

I have created a custom dialog box in C#.  I have a combobox, an Ok button and a Cancel button on the dialog box form.  When the user clicks the ok button, I would like to return the selectedItem from the combobox.  My dialog box form is created and works.  It returns the correct dialog results.  I just cannot find a way to get the combobox selected item before the form is disposed of.

Comment: Please add any code you currently have and let us know what you have tried and what the results were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a public property of the form:

```
public string SelectedItem {
    get {
        return comboBox.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
}
```

..then your `ShowDialog` call should be something like this:

```
if (yourDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    var selectedItem = yourDialog.SelectedItem;
    // do stuff with it here
}
```

This assumes that your OK button has a `DialogResult` value of `OK` set in its properties.

Comment: I just had to make one change:                                  public string SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return tankSelector.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }
        }